# 2 Scrollbars visible when I open a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

We have a baffling issue whereby when we try to open a modal dialog box from a parent page it opens with 2 vertical scrollbars next to each other. One controls the modal box, the other one controls the main page behind it.

To have 2 scrollbars is not ideal and have tried to implement a solution for this.
We added some javascript in the dialog box page which would set the  style to overflow:hidden when the modal dialog is open.

```
<script>
function myOnLoad() {
    window.parent.$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
}
```

and used....

```
<body onload="myOnLoad()">
```

This works and effectively removes the scrollbar in the page behind it (i.e it does what it should) however we also want to set the overflow back to ‘auto’ when the modal dialog is closed…

We have done this by adding this code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// close Modal
$("#close").click(function () {
window.parent.$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
window.parent.$("iframe").attr('src', '');
window.parent.$(".modalDialog").removeClass('show');
});
```

However this does not seem to work as the modal dialog closes but the scrollbar is still hidden on the main page.
Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong here? I have tried different overflow properties but nothing seems to work

Comment: "when we try to open a modal dialog box from a parent page", what does that mean? And why all the complication with `window.parent`?

Comment: A modal is in the same window. A popup is in another window. Are you using a modal or a popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok try this, I think your page is reloading on click and thus executing your onload:

```
$("#close").click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
window.parent.$('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
window.parent.$("iframe").attr('src', '');
window.parent.$(".modalDialog").removeClass('show');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked. Yes it did appear to be re-loading the page on click

Comment: @Chris No problem. Please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think that using window.parent might be the problem since this refers to the parent of the iframe wich is gone. or something like that. just use jquery

you can try by just getting the body directly  $("body"), asuming you are getting that click function to fire.

edit: i see this has been mentioned above

Answer (score -1):

Add style to body as

```
body
{
     padding-right:0px !important;
     overflow-y:hidden !important;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?